# Are the developer's guides outdated?

Tags: monero-wallet-rpc

I was trying to find docs about how to create a new subaddress using the CLI wallet RPC but it seems that dev guides at https://getmonero.org/resources/developer-guides/ are not updated to reflect 0.12.* version.

Are they simply not updated or there is another reason to be in the current state?

Is there an issue tracker where to report this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I know the daemon RPC guide has recently been fully updated and the wallet RPC guide has recent updates.

Issues can be tracked (and contributions to update) at https://github.com/monero-project/monero-site/

Answer (score 1):

Deamon RPC developer guide is up-to-date.
I did the refresh with the help of moneromooo

However, the wallet RPC is partially outdated. Only the subaddress-related stuffs have been recently added.
It's in my todo list to do a refresh on this too.